# Chrome Android body height: 100% is actually longer than viewport

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

On Chrome on Android, I've had an issue recently where even though I'm setting the body height and width to 100%, the body of my page appears to be slightly longer than the viewport, causing things to look a bit off.

To try to get to the bottom of the problem, I stripped the page down to the following barebones page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            *{
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            html, body{ 
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            body{
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

When viewed on a desktop, it looks fine

[image: Test page on desktop]

When viewed on Android on Chrome, it looks like this

[image: Test page on Android Chrome]

So for some reason, it seems the actual body of the page is longer than the 100% it's been set at, so the border gets cut off. It looks like there's about a 2px difference, which isn't much, but it's enough to make my design look off.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Or is this a bug in Chrome (or my phone!)?

Answer (score 1):

try setting height to 100svh

height: 100svh;